# Reacting on serialize and deserialize of an instance

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a class which i am serializing. I annotated it with `[Serializable]` and i am using binary serializer. Everything works fine.

But later i introduced new properties, which cannot be serialized (lets say they contain a lot of mess about GUI which does not need to be rembered). I can compute these properties based on other properties of class.

I need to do it two times, when I serialize - clean mess and enter stabile state ready for serialization. And deserialization - again compute all needed properties.

I need to react on 'events' instance is being serialized/deserialized.

However I can't find these events because I am not implementing the interface `ISerializable` or abstract class `Aserializable` but only class atribute `[Serializable]`.

I do not know when class is being serialized  because it is not the concern of this class; it is serialized as a field of another class.

Is there a way I can react on those events?

Comment: You must implement `ISerializable` to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OnDeserializedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) and its related attributes (OnSerializing, OnSerialized, OnDeserializing) to create special methods that are called during the serialization/deserialization process.

Answer (score 0):

Build [Custome Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) by Implementing ISerializable. Use [OnSerializingAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), to manipulate object before serilazation and [OnDeserializingAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), to manipulate before deserialization.

Comment: Note that you only need to implement ISerializable if you plan to interact with the serialization process itself.  For the OP's case, it's sufficient to use the attributes and 'serialization event' methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered per chance the  `[XmlIgnoreAttribute]` attribute? It will prevent a property to be serialized. No need to tamper withe the serialization workflow.

My bad, didn't realize you wanted to reload some property on deserialization. So why not serialize these? In an optional subObject, or whatever?

Comment: He is using the binary serializer. `[XmlIgnoreAttribute]` has no effect on the binary serializer. You would use NonSerialized if you were serializing to binary or SOAP, and XmlIgnore if you were strictly serializing to XML using an XmlSerializer.  See the remarks section of the `[NonSerializedAttribute]` class at MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx

Comment: Dutifuly noted. Thank you. But the question remains: why not use the vanilla serialization, with the 'disaply' attributes, or without them + value computing in the GET accessor?